# Laravel, images not loading from storage folder

Tags: php, laravel

Images are not loading on site. just getting a ***404 image not found***.

- i have tried using removing /public/storage and running the `php artisan storage:link` command, but no
  luck.

Current filesystems config:

```
 'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

logo is in `/storage/logo/logo.png`

Loading logo:

```
<img src="{{asset(Storage::url('logo/logo.png'))}}" class="navbar-brand-img mx-auto" alt="{{ env('APP_NAME') }}">/>
```

Maybe its a folder permisson issue?

Answer (score 0):

i use this driver

```
'images' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('images/'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ]
```

this driver path is  public/images and for save by this dirver just use

```
$request->file('avatar')->store('members', 'images');
```